# shell script tar script -s option

Tags: shell, tar

What does following code do? I am interested in knowing what `-s '@^Packages@FreeNAS/Packages@'` does exactly.

```
tar -c -p -f ${NANO_OBJ}/gui-packages.tar \
    -s '@^Packages@FreeNAS/Packages@' \
    -C ${NANO_OBJ}/_.packages .
```

Answer (score 0):

`-s` option modifies file or archive member names according to given pattern. Which is this:

```
-s '@^Packages@FreeNAS/Packages@'
```

meaning search for text `Packages` and substitute by `FreeNAS/Packages`. `@` is regex delimiter.

As per `man tar`:

> `-s pattern`
>
> Modify file or archive member names according to pattern.  The pattern has the format /old/new/[gps] where old is
>                a basic regular expression, new is the replacement string of the matched part, and the optional trailing letters
>                modify how the replacement is handled.  If old is not matched, the pattern is skipped.  Within new, ~ is substi-
>                tuted with the match, 1 to 9 with the content of the corresponding captured group.  The optional trailing g spec-
>                ifies that matching should continue after the matched part and stopped on the first unmatched pattern.  The
>                optional trailing s specifies that the pattern applies to the value of symbolic links.  The optional trailing p
>                specifies that after a successful substitution the original path name and the new path name should be printed to
>                standard error.